# How to get list of All Objects enabled with Activities?

Tags: apex, describesobject, activities

Is there anyway we can find all Objects which have Activities enabled, in APEX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most accurate and quickest way is to loop over the list of valid target Objects of the `WhatId` field on the `Task` or `Event` object, as this list will change whenever you check/uncheck the "Allow Activities" checkbox on a given Object:

```
Set<Schema.SObjectType> objectsWithActivitiesEnabled = new Set<Schema.SObjectType>();
String objectNames = '';
for (Schema.SObjectType objectType : Task.WhatId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) {
   objectsWithActivitiesEnabled.add(objectType);
   objectNames += '\n' + objectType;
}

system.debug(objectNames);
```

Comment: haha, this is way simpler than my method. I thought there was something like getreferenceTo but I must have missed it when I was checking the documentation.

Comment: Thanks guys. This worked. But i guess there should be some standard approach to gather Activity enabled objects from DescribesObjectresult methods.

Comment: I would argue that this *is* the standard approach. From an API perspective, all that "enabling Activities on an Object" does is add a given SObject to the list of possible endpoints of the Polymorphic `WhatId` field common to both the `Task` and `Event` Objects. All other areas of the Salesforce API, I believe, read from this list when determining which Objects to present Activity-related functionality for, e.g. the various Activities related lists, the list of drop-down options next to the "Related To" field. And this list is precisely the content of the `getReferenceTo()` list given above.